# Why display:inline-flex Make the window horizontally scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want that **cards** moves from right to left with same height and width as shown in **picture** which works fine but i am  getting window *horizontally scrollable which i don't want*. When i am putting `width:100%` the **card width reduced** which i don't want. when the number of cards is less everything works fine but not with no of cards increases. So please help me to get this work as i want.

***Like cards should be the same height and width as shown in picture without horizontally scrollable window***

[image]

```css
.main-ind-card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;



  /*align-content : flex-start;*/
  /*!*max-width: fit-content;*!*/
  /*align-items: flex-start;*/

   overflow-x:hidden; 
   align-items: stretch;


}


.ind-card {
  width: 280px;
  height: 150px;
  max-width:100%;

  background: rgb(17, 4, 134);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: rgb(0,0,0,0.7) 5px 10px 50px ,rgb(0,0,0,0.7) -5px 0px 250px;
  /*display: flex;*/

  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(20, 30, 48), rgb(36, 59, 85));
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left:20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  animation: ind-card 8s infinite linear;
margin-right:auto;



}


@keyframes ind-card {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
  33.333% {
    transform: translateX(-200px)
  }
  66.666% {
    transform: translateX(-400px)
  }
  99.999% {
    transform: translateX(-600px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
}




.ind-card:hover {
  box-shadow: rgb(0,0,0) 5px 10px 50px ,rgb(0,0,0) -5px 0px 250px;



}

.top {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-block-end: .5rem;
}

.pfp {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title-1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}


.playing {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
}

.greenline {
  background-color: #1db954;
  height: 20px;
  width: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.line-1 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.line-2 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.line-3 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.line-4 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.line-5 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

@keyframes playing {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }

  33% {
    transform: scaleY(0.6);
  }

  66% {
    transform: scaleY(0.9);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-ind-card">

<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ind-card" width="280px" height="150px";>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Hiding overflow on the body will hide the scrollbar, although it will also remove the ability to scroll horizontally. CSS: `body { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/0v7fe3p2/

Comment: @evolutionxbox this reduce the card width

Comment: Including [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38994837/989920)? How does it do that?

Comment: @jla 'main-ind-card { overflow: hidden; }' doesnt removing the horizontal scroll bar

Comment: @RahulVerma you need to do `overflow: hidden` on the _parent_ of `.main-ind-card` (or rather, the nearest ancestor that is 100% of the viewport width); hence why I suggested doing it on `body`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox none of these working you can try by yourself

Comment: @RahulVerma did you see my comment even?

Comment: @Leothelion ya i did this 'overflow-x: hidden;'

Comment: Yes. i was saying to remove that scroll bar and showed you my fiddle where there is no scroll bar. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Leothelion Ya thats i want but why you uses 'body' why its not working inside 'main-ind-card'

Comment: @RahulVerma because scroll bar is coming on body you have to apply overflow hidden on body. simple.  Are you getting any issue with body or is it solving your query?

Comment: @Leothelion Its solved my issue one more thing 'text-align: center', 'align-items: center' doesn't make text in center what i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just give `min-width:280px`to `.ind-card` class
and `width:100%` to `.main-ind-card` class.

check the result there is no scroll bar at bottom and images are moving from right to left.
[image]

Comment: getting same result.

Comment: check your code again i attached the image and it is working as you want

Answer (score 1):

Give the `.main-ind-card` `width: 100%` and `overflow-x: clip` properties. The width will explicitly tell it how it should be sized. The `clip` overflow behaves the same as `hidden` but allows your `box-shadow` to stay correct.

Setting the width will make the flex children fit in the space. This is because the flex children are told to shrink and grow by default. In this case we can disable the shrink with `flex-shrink: 0`.

```css
.main-ind-card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  
  overflow-x: clip;
  width: 100%;
}

.ind-card {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  
  width: 280px;
  height: 150px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: rgb(17, 4, 134);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 5px 10px 50px, rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7) -5px 0px 250px;
  /*display: flex;*/
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(20, 30, 48), rgb(36, 59, 85));
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: ind-card 8s infinite linear;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@keyframes ind-card {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
  33.333% {
    transform: translateX(-200px)
  }
  66.666% {
    transform: translateX(-400px)
  }
  99.999% {
    transform: translateX(-600px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
}

.ind-card:hover {
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 5px 10px 50px, rgb(0, 0, 0) -5px 0px 250px;
}

.top {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-block-end: .5rem;
}

.pfp {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title-1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.playing {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
}

.greenline {
  background-color: #1db954;
  height: 20px;
  width: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.line-1 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.line-2 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.line-3 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.line-4 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.line-5 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

@keyframes playing {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  33% {
    transform: scaleY(0.6);
  }
  66% {
    transform: scaleY(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-ind-card">

  <div class="ind-card">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="pfp">
        <div class="playing">
          <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="texts">
        <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ind-card">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="pfp">
        <div class="playing">
          <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="texts">
        <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="ind-card">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="pfp">
        <div class="playing">
          <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="texts">
        <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ind-card">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="pfp">
        <div class="playing">
          <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="texts">
        <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ind-card">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="pfp">
        <div class="playing">
          <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="texts">
        <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ind-card">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="pfp">
        <div class="playing">
          <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="texts">
        <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ind-card">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="pfp">
        <div class="playing">
          <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="texts">
        <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ind-card" width="280px" height="150px" ;>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="pfp">
        <div class="playing">
          <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
          <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="texts">
        <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `width: 100%` to `.main-id-card` and set `min-width` instead of `width` to `280px` for `.ind-card`.

```css
.main-ind-card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;



  /*align-content : flex-start;*/
  /*!*max-width: fit-content;*!*/
  /*align-items: flex-start;*/

   overflow-x:hidden; 
   align-items: stretch;


}


.ind-card {
  min-width: 280px;
  height: 150px;
  max-width:100%;

  background: rgb(17, 4, 134);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: rgb(0,0,0,0.7) 5px 10px 50px ,rgb(0,0,0,0.7) -5px 0px 250px;
  /*display: flex;*/

  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(20, 30, 48), rgb(36, 59, 85));
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left:20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  animation: ind-card 8s infinite linear;
margin-right:auto;



}


@keyframes ind-card {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
  33.333% {
    transform: translateX(-200px)
  }
  66.666% {
    transform: translateX(-400px)
  }
  99.999% {
    transform: translateX(-600px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
}




.ind-card:hover {
  box-shadow: rgb(0,0,0) 5px 10px 50px ,rgb(0,0,0) -5px 0px 250px;



}

.top {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-block-end: .5rem;
}

.pfp {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title-1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}


.playing {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
}

.greenline {
  background-color: #1db954;
  height: 20px;
  width: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.line-1 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.line-2 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.line-3 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.line-4 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.line-5 {
  animation: infinite playing 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

@keyframes playing {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }

  33% {
    transform: scaleY(0.6);
  }

  66% {
    transform: scaleY(0.9);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-ind-card">

<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ind-card">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ind-card" width="280px" height="150px";>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="pfp">
      <div class="playing">
        <div class="greenline line-1"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-2"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-3"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-4"></div>
        <div class="greenline line-5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="texts">
      <p class="title-1">Real Estate</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `flex-wrap: wrap` property.

refer: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/

Comment: Giving different result cards divided in 2 rows.